# Знак "сыщик". Что значит "первое сообщение, неактивное в течение 6 месяцев"?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, знаки

Знак ["Сыщик"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator) содержит такое описание:

> [image: Ошибочный перевод сыщика]

Как понимать "в первое сообщение"? А какое сообщение, неактивное в течение 6 месяцев считается первым и какое вторым?

Быть может, имеется в виду нечто вроде "Впервые внести правку в сообщение, неактивное в течение 6 месяцев"?

Comment: *Впервые внести правку в сообщение, неактивное в течение 6 месяцев*, за это и будет знак

Comment: @L.F.C. Ну в таком случае, вероятно, стоит внести изменения в формулировку описания.

Comment: Скорее всего, необходимо внести предложение

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оригинальный текст выглядит так:

> Edit first post that was inactive for 6 months

[Перевод](https://ru.traducir.win/string/6193) поправлен в соответствии предложением в [комментарии](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/9318/#comment38537_9318):

> Впервые внести правку в сообщение, неактивное в течение 6 месяцев

Появится на сайте после череды обновлений.

Comment: Даже в оригинале странновато, как по мне. А я грешил на локализацию.